# Are shift-chains two-colorable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrepancy-theory, hypergraph

For $A\subset [n]$ denote by $a_i$ the $i^{th}$ smallest element of $A$.

For two $k$-element sets, $A,B\subset [n]$, we say that $A\le B$ if $a_i\le b_i$ for every $i$.

A $k$-uniform hypergraph ${\mathcal H}\subset [n]$ is called a {\em shift-chain} if for any hyperedges, $A, B \in {\mathcal H}$, we have $A\le B$ or $B\le A$. (So a shift-chain has at most $k(n-k)+1$ hyperedges.)

We say that a hypergraph  ${\mathcal H}$ is two-colorable if we can color its vertices with two colors such that no hyperedge is monochromatic.

Is it true that shift-chains are two-colorable if $k$ is large enough?

**Remarks.** The problem was investigated on the 1st Emlektabla Workshop for some partial results, see the [booklet](http://www.renyi.hu/~emlektab/index_booklet.html).

The question is motivated by decomposition of multiple coverings of the plane by translates of convex shapes, there are many open questions in this area. (For more, see my [brand new thesis](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~dom/cikkek/thesis.pdf).)

For $k=2$ there is a trivial counterexample: (12),(13),(23).

A very magical counterexample was given for $k=3$ by Radoslav Fulek with a computer program:

(123),(124),(125),(135),(145),(245),(345),(346),(347),(357),

(367),(467),(567),(568),(569),(579),(589),(689),(789).

If we allow the hypergraph to be the union of two shift-chains (with the same order), then there is a counterexample for any $k$.

**Edit.** I crossposted the question at [cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/do-shift-chain-have-property-b).

**Permanent bounty!** I'm happy to award a 500 bounty for a solution anytime!

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps a somewhat silly observation, but can't you always find a non-monochromatic coloring with 3 colors?

First of all, if we can find a good coloring for any shift-chain with sets of size $k_0$, then we can find good colorings for any shift-chain with sets of size $k > k_0$, simply by taking the shift-chain that contains the lowest (or highest) $k_0$ elements of each of the sets. So it's enough to show the claim for $k=2$.

We can also assume that neighboring sets in the shift-chain differ by only one element that increases by one step (otherwise we can simply introduce intermediate sets).

So the case of $k=2$ can be thought of as alternating sequences of the higher element $b$ racing ahead and the lower element $a$ trying to catch up. Let us construct a coloring in a greedy way. The invariant is that there are always at most two colors in the interval $[a,b)$.

As long as $b$ increases, we keep its color constant. When $b$ reaches the point where it "rests" for a while, we have to do some case distinction. In the case where $a$ would catch up until it has the same color that $b$ used to have, we change the color of $b$ to the third available color (remember the invariant!). Thus there will be no monochromatic $\{a,b\}$ in the phase where $a$ tries to keep up. If $a$ does not reach the region where it would have the same color as $b$, then we keep $b$'s color the same even though it is waiting, so that the invariant is not violated when $b$ starts racing ahead again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact, Rado also proved this, I don't know why they did not include it in the booklet, there you can find the statement that cyclic shift-chains are 5 colorable. Did you think about coming to the 2nd Emlektabla?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it looks like I won't be able to make it since I'm already travelling for most of January. Perhaps next year (well, 2012, that is).

Comment: We might have one on the summer as well. Then have a nice trip, see you in the spring hopefully.